# Ruby: Limit size writing to text file while using gsub

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

Currently working on parsing out some error logs. I'm using ruby and the `File` library. I encounter about 381 instances of the word `uid` which I'm replacing with empty string using `gsub`.

[image]

However, when I replace the `uid` with new string only 9 instances of it are shown. I'm not sure if there is a size limit to what you can do with `gsub`.

```
file_input = ARGV[0]

text = File.read(file_input)

 replace = text.gsub(/uid/,'*********************************
 BEGINNING OF SUBMISSION *****************************************************')
File.open('testing.txt', "w") do |file|
  file << replace 
end
```

When I open up `testing.txt` the file is about 15 lines which is drastic contrast to the one being passed into `file_input` which is about 700 lines and has 381 mentiones of the word `uid`. Is there a limit?

Comment: `gsub` haven't limit, looks like problem in another place. I tried to run your script on this file: https://gist.github.com/X1ting/b45952550253becee8bc5fb4696e072e results looks OK, all `uid` sequences were replaced. Can you provide file which works incorrect?

Comment: The file I'm using has sensitive data I can not provide. But let me look for something similar.